# Sliding down and up with nested div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written codes but they won`t work, please kindly help me!
I have a div with two other div nested into. the first div has h2 tag that should be clicked in order to show the the content of the second div, then click again to hide the content.
here I have my codes, please debug it and help me move forward.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#toggle").click(function(){
 
         if ($(this).is(":visible")){
             $(".item-body").slidDown("normal");
         } else {
             $(".item-body").slideUp("normal");
         }
     });
 });
```

```css
.my-item{
 width:250px;
 heigth:180px;
 margin:10px;
 padding:20px;
 background:green;
 border:2px solid black;
}
.item-header{
 width:150px;
 heigth:120px;
 margin:5px;
 padding:10px;
 background:yellow;
 border:1px solid black;
}
.item-body{
 width:70px;
 heigth:50px;
 margin:3px;
 padding:5px;
 background:purple;
 border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Demo</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
 <div class="my-item">
 <div class="item-header">
 <h2 id="toggle">Click Me!</h2>
 <div class="item-body">My Text!
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Just a quick spot question.  Where are you changing the visibility of the toggle?  Your sliding the sibling item body.

Comment: this is the detailed question. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not talking about what your trying to do.  I'm talking about what you -are- doing.  '$(this).is(":visible")'  In the context of your click handler 'this' is the toggle element, and as far as i can tell from your logic, it's always visible.

Comment: I`m going to slideUp and slideDown the item-body by clicking h2 tag in item-header

Comment: Which changes the visibility of the item-body, not the toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your first `if` statement to the following:

```
if ($(".item-body").is(":visible")) {
```

Instead of checking if the `h1` is visible (which it always will be), this will solve the issue.

**Other notes**

- You have a typo with your `slideDown()` missing an 'e'.
- You should switch the `slideUp()` and the `slideDown()` so that it `slideUp()`s when it's visible and it `slideDown()`s if it is not — see my below example.

See [this working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ctjzg74/1/).

Comment: Thanks a million, now it works. :)- I made a silly mistake. :D

Comment: @Mahtab I'm glad I helped! (just make sure to "accept" this answer if it did &mdash; press that green check!)